# Export svg for every layer in Inkscape

Tags: python, svg, export, inkscape

I'm trying to write an extension that will export an svg file for every layer in my inkscape scene. I can't seem to get this to work. The code runs, but there is not output. Here is my code:

```
import inkex
import subprocess
    
class MyExportExtension(inkex.EffectExtension):

    #add_arguments is currently not being used
    def add_arguments(self, pars):
        pars.add_argument("--my_option", type=inkex.Boolean,\
            help="An example option, put your options here")

    def run_command(self, args):
        try:
            with subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
            proc.wait(timeout=300)
        except OSError:
            inkex.errormsg('Program "%s" is not installed!' % args[0])
            exit()    

    def svg_export(self, layer_id, file):
        self.run_command([
          'inkscape',
          '--without-gui',
          '--export-filename=%s' % file,
          '--export-area-page',
          '--export-id=%s' % layer_id,
          '--export-id-only',
          '--export-plain-svg'
        ])

    def effect(self):
        export_folder_path = 'C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/test_folder/test_export_location/'

        for layer in self.document.xpath('//svg:g[@inkscape:groupmode="layer"]', namespaces=inkex.NSS):
            layer_id = layer.attrib["id"]
            layer_label = layer.attrib["{%s}label" % layer.nsmap['inkscape']]
            file = export_folder_path + layer_label
            self.svg_export(layer_id, file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyExportExtension().run()
```

Comment: Is the `effect` method executed? Does the `for layer...` loop have more than 0 iterations?

Comment: Yes, the effect method is executed. And the 'for layer...' does have more than 0 iterations. This code is a simplified version of my work in progress, and in my WIP I have the code export a log file with the layer names from within the 'effect' function.

Comment: So is `svg_export` called? Is `run_command` called? Are the correct `args` passed to `run_command`? Does `subprocess.Popen` raise an exception? Does `proc.wait` return? (Note that the indentation of the `with` block is wrong in the code you have shown, so you should get an error there, and you should double check that the code you are showing matches the code you are actually running.)

Comment: Yes, everything is called. No exceptions are raised. The indentation is wrong in the code I have shown, thanks for catching that. I wanted to edit it just now, but it isn't letting me for some odd reason. About the correct args being passed to run_command, that's honestly where I was hoping someone might be able to help. I believe I'm doing it right, but I'm new to inkscape. I put this together based on other existing extensions. I'm also wondering if what I'm doing is obsolete, since there was a major inkscape update that was done and these extensions predate that.